# I don't remember all my ME2 choices. Can I look them up somehow?

Tags: mass-effect-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I view the outcomes of decisions from past games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56046/can-i-view-the-outcomes-of-decisions-from-past-games)

I played through ME2 rather haphazardly, saving, reloading, and branching games. I'm not sure what choices I made in the savegame I ended up importing, especially with respect to the heretic geth etc.

Is there a way, perhaps with some savegame magic, to get a list of the choices I made in ME2?

Comment: I believe that, when starting ME3 and importing a save, it will summarize your choices

Comment: this sounds like a toughie.

Comment: I have a nagging feeling that this question has already been asked, but I can't find it.  In any case @DaveMcClelland, the summary only gives the Big 10 or so, and not the 1000+ variables that are tracked.

Comment: @MBraedley I believe I saw a similar question for ME1->ME2, but don't recall seeing one for ME2->ME3.  You are correct though, some decision are omitted from the list for brevity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Savegame Magic!](http://social.bioware.com/project/4373/#files)

This will also let you edit choices from Mass Effect 1.  Work appears to be on going to get all the ME2 plot choices in, but most of the major ones are there.